# Complex number \$e^{jk\pi} = (-1)^k\$

Tags: basic

I know that \$e^{jk2\pi}\$ or \$e^{\mathrm{integer}}\$ will give you 1, but I can't find the proof for why \$e^{jk\pi} = (-1)^k\$.

Can someone please explain how \$e^{jk\pi} = (-1)^k\$?

[image: Workings]

Does it have to do with the fact that it is a multiple of \$\pi\$ and not multiple of \$2\pi\$?

Comment: The origin of this equation lies in signals. Evey sinusoidal signal is composed of infinitely many exponentials. But sine and cosine are periodic functions with period 2*pi and also have half symmetry. You can explore this concept to get an intuitive idea of your question.

Answer (score 5):

There is a very famous identity, know as [Euler's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity), which says:

$$e^{i\pi}+1=0 \rightarrow e^{i\pi}=-1$$

It's an identity which should be known by *all* engineers and mathematicians, and you can simply substitute it in when needed.

As to your question

$$a^{bc} = (a^b)^c$$

so

$$e^{ik\pi}=(e^{i\pi})^k=(-1)^k$$

---

In case you are wondering, and as described in full on the Wiki article in the above link, this comes from the [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula):

$$e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$$

What happens when you set \$x = \pi\$?

Well, you get:

$$e^{i\pi} = \cos (\pi) + i\sin (\pi) = -1 + 0i = -1$$

Comment: i figure this out right after posting this question, but thank you for answering since I am now sure that how I came up with the answer is correct